Next.js 14 favicon.ico file doesn't show up in chrome
Just simply replace  favicon.ico , chrome cannot show it. It seems like a bug.  I use app router.
/-app
/-favicon.ico

I found out many encountered this problems , I found out how to solve this problem:
1.Rename favicon.ico to icon.ico then move icon.ico to src/app folder. It's work now.

true i also observed this behavior, and seems like windows OS somewhere also cache the preview of the ico file even in folder view the latest icon does not reflect often unless your rename. Yes can say for sure, its cache issues of windows explorer i think and latest file does not get picked in the first place.

OR
Use icon.png in /public folder.  not directly in /app.  Be aware of refer the image in layout.jsx
//layout.jsx

   
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "something",
  description: "something"
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
      </head>
      
    </html>
  );
}





In Nextjs 13
add code here in _document.tsx,js,ts
 <Head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/ico.png" />
 </Head>

href="/ico.png" link public/ico.png
In Nextjs 14
add ico in app folder
File convention      Supported file types                Valid locations
favicon               .ico                             app/
icon              .ico, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .svg        app/**/*
apple-icon        .jpg, .jpeg, .png                    app/**/*

